# Pull Bitcoin price from web site?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that pulls the live Bitcoin price from Coinbase.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.coinbase.com/charts?locale=en-US/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
print soup.title.string
```

When I run it, the only output I get is:

```
Bitcoin, Ethereum, and Litecoin Price Charts - Coinbase
```

How do I get it so I can pull the number?

Also, if I wanted to keep the program running constantly so it would update the price live, how would I do that?

Comment: Read something on the page other than `soup.title`. The only output you're going to get from `title` is **exactly** that - the **title**. Why would you expect anything else?

Comment: `soup.title` just gets the title of the page. Are you trying to get the content of a specific element on the page? Check out BeautifulSoup's [find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) function.

Answer (score 0):

the number is loaded via javascript ajax... so this technique wont work ... at all

instead try this (access the same url they are loading the actual price from)

```
import requests
value = float(requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?").json()['data'][0]['amount'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The number itself doesn't come in that page. You can see yourself if you check the html. The page requests the data using Ajax requests.

If you open the network tab in your browser's web development console, you'll see it periodically calls this url: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?

So you can load that url directly, it returns a json string you can decode to obtain the value you are looking for:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?'
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.json()
print(data['data'][0]['amount'])
```

That said, they probably won't be happy if you simply use their API like that. Check if they have an official developer's API you can use.